# getting string from one ViewController to another?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, uitextfield

I have been working on my application for a while now. I am stuck on this small problem: setting my text field's `text` isn't working.The string of the text field is called from another viewcontroller Here is what my code looks like:

1st view controller
    -(void)setURL:(NSURL *)src
    {
        downloadSourceField.text = src;
    }
2nd view controller

```
if ([[booksArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",song_1]]) 
{
    NSString *sc1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tst 1"];
    [tc setURL:sc1];
}

else 
{
    NSString *sc = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"test 2"];
    [tc setURL:sc];
}
```

Comment: If the text field is created in Interface Builder, double check the connection.  Sending a message (setText: in this case) to a nil object will fail silently.

Comment: I have made the text field in the interface builder and have made sure it is all hooked up to it outlets and everything

Comment: Are you getting errors? If not, set a breakpoint on that line and check the variables. I would suspect that either downloadSourceField or src is nil (0x0).

Comment: downloadsourcefield is set to nil and that is what i am trying to change and set it to the text that is stored in src

Comment: okay now when i nslog the src it works fine but now when i try to put it in the uitextfield it changes to (null) for some reason

Comment: do one thing take src into another string and pass to the downloadSourceField.text it ll works.If there is still problem then go for IB connections or downloadSourceField.text=nil statement(if any where u write in the code )

Comment: Try NSLog() downloadSourceField and see if it's nil or not. If it's nil, you haven't connected things right.

Comment: It is connected properly and it is being set to nil

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to assign an NSURL object to an NSString variable. What you should do is

```
downloadSourceField.text = [src absoluteString];
```

The absoluteString method will convert your NSURL into an NSString representation.

Comment: please have a look at the comments above and look into the matter